# How to move the code from Dev to QA branches in TFS?

Tags: tfs, merge

**Intro:**

Dev branch has the code that is deployed to the development environment and where development happens, QA branch is what gets deployed to the QA environment so QAs can test.

**My question is:**

After I am done working on the code in the Dev environment and has checked it into the Dev branch. What is the easiest way to move the changeset (or the code I have changed in Dev) from the Dev branch to the QA branch?

Comment: Have you heard of [_Merging_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge+tfs)?

Comment: Merging described http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, there is another understanding for this question. It is possible to really move code from one branch to other without performing merge. This would be useful if the code is for different products but under the same Team Project. Nevertheless, I understand  branches Dev and QA reflects the same product, so a merge would be the  appropriate process, as stated by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be very new to Source Control and Branching and Merging process. The process of moving one changeset (or a range of changesets) from a branch to another is called merging.

I suggest you look into [Merge Folders and Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428.aspx) on MSDN that explains how to perform a merge.

Other excellent resources that might aid your understanding are the Wrox [ALM](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1118314085/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_2?ie=UTF8&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE) and [TFS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1118314093/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_1?ie=UTF8&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE) books and the [ALM Rangers Branching and Merging Guidance](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/96396) (in increasing in technical level order).